# Could not autowire hibernate SessionFactory in dao class

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, configuration

i have a problem injecting a hibernate sessionfactory bean in my dao class. saying there is no bean qualified with that name

```
@Repository("emaildao")
public class EmailDAOImpl implements EmailDAO{  

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory s){
    sessionFactory = s;
}

@Override
public void saveMessages(List<Message> messages) {
    // some code persisting messages
}
```

here is my config files

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.opm.emailheader" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean    
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.opm.emailheader"}             );
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
 }

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.query_cache", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.query_cache"));
    properties.put("hibernate.query_cache_size", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.query_cache_size"));            
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibarnate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.CharSet","utf8");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding","utf8");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode",true);

    return properties;

}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new     HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
   return txManager;
}
```

the code structure folder is like:
com.opm.emailheader

- app

  > > dao
  > >
  > > > daoimpl
- conf

  > > > HibernateConfiguration.java
  > > >       AppInitializer.java
  > > >       WebConfig.java
  > > >       SecurityConfig.java

the exception stack trace :
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emaildao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.opm.emailheader.app.dao.daoimpl.EmailDAOImpl.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT68e.png)

Comment: Can you write the package of EmailDAOImpl, plz?

Comment: please check package names

Comment: i have added a picture of all project structure.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT68e.png